# can I query for documents in specific Elasticsearch shard?

Tags: elasticsearch

we are using [custom routing](https://www.elastic.co/blog/customizing-your-document-routing) and ended up with a single shard that is over 100gb and I'd like to know which routing value is causing this imbalance...

I can see the shards like this...

```
GET /_cat/shards

my-index 2 p STARTED 10108264 131.5gb  
my-index 3 p STARTED   270403   1.7gb 
my-index 1 p STARTED   187303   1.5gb 
my-index 0 p STARTED   321519   2.5gb
```

and see the shard details like this..

```
GET /my-index/_search_shards
```

and even see shard info for random documents like this...

```
GET /my-index/_search
{
  "explain": true
}
```

but how can I search for documents in a specific shard (shard #2 in my case)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Should be able to do that using the [preference](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-preference.html) option:

Example:

```
GET my-index/_search?preference=_shards:2
```

Comment: is there no _shards:1 ? when i type it, it returns an error